# Print first page from each of 1000 PDF

Tags: batch-file, pdf, vbscript, cmd, batch-processing

By using .bat and .vbs. How it's possible to print first page from each of 1000 PDFs?

The only working solution, which I found is:

```
Option Explicit

Const FILE_TO_PRINT = "n:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxxx.PDF"
Dim shl
Dim fldr
Dim files,file

Set shl = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set fldr = shl.Namespace("n:\HEAT06\BAA Cards\66712\20161103\")
Set files = fldr.Items


For Each file in files
  If LCase(file.Path) = LCase(FILE_TO_PRINT) Then
    file.InvokeVerbEx("Print")
  End If

Next

Set shl = Nothing
Set fldr = Nothing
Set files = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

it's does work, BUT it will print whole document, when I need only first page.

Comment: Does Acrobat have an interface like Word.Application? http://www.visualbasicscript.com/vbs-to-print-three-pages-from-ms-word-m70929.aspx

Comment: Which Programm is used for PDF printing? Adobe Reader?

Comment: @ReFran Using Adobe Acrobat 11 Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attached a VBS I wrote some years ago that will print the first page of all files you drop on it to the default printer. You may change it to that what you need. If you use it with drag & drop, keep in mind, that you have to **drag** the marked files **from the first or last file** in order to get the printouts sorted in the way you marked the files. HTH, Reinhard

```
 '//Print first page of pdfs

set WshShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments

if objArgs.Count < 1 then
    msgbox("Please drag a file on the script")
    WScript.quit
end if
    'contact Acrobat
Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
gApp.show 'comment or take out to work in hidden mode

  'open via Avdoc and print
for i=0 to objArgs.Count - 1
    FileIn = ObjArgs(i)
    Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    If AVDoc.Open(FileIn, "") Then
        Set PDDoc = AVDoc.GetPDDoc()
        Set JSO = PDDoc.GetJSObject
        jso.print false, 0, 0, true
        gApp.CloseAllDocs
    end if
next

gApp.hide : gApp.exit : Quit()
MsgBox "Done!"

Sub Quit
  Set JSO = Nothing : Set PDDoc = Nothing : Set gApp =Nothing : Wscript.quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

after installing Ghostscript you can use the following code (open a notepad and after saving it change the extension to .bat). You have to place the .bat file in the same folder you have the PDFs you want to print.

The code is (gswin64c.exe may change if you have a newer version of Ghostscript)

```
for %%I in (*.pdf) do "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.55.0\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE#pdfwrite -sOutputFile#"%%~nI-page1.pdf" -dFirstPage#1 -dLastPage#1 "%%I"
```

Your question is very old but hopefully this will avoid someone else spending hours like I just did to solve it haha